# Nodemon, babel-node is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, babeljs, node-modules, nodemon

I have been trying to initiate the localhost with `npm start` but getting this error in terminal:

```
[nodemon] 2.0.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): backend\**\*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `babel-node backend/server.js`
'babel-node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

The `package.json` in the root folder is:

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "ABC",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --watch backend --exec babel-node backend/server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/node": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

I also have these files in the node_modules.

- node_modules/.bin/babel-node
- node_modules/.bin/babel-node.cmd
- node_modules/@babel/node/bin/babel-node.js

I just started working in node and cannot figure out how to solve this. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Delete package-lock.json
2. Delete folder node_modules and all its content
3. Install global babel node  : npm install -g @babel\node
4. re-install all packages : npm install
5. restart your application : npm start